# python os.fork() for performing operation under degraded credentials

Tags: python, fork

I'm looking to implement the following command in python.

```
su ${USER} -c "whoami"
```

which simply create child process which runs under different privilege, and return the result of `whoami` back to the parent process.

As bash works, It should be done using `os.fork()` while the result is retrieved to parent process once the Chile process terminate its work.

```
def runWhoamiOtherUser(self):
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        os.setuid(getpwnam(os.environ['USER'])[2])
        x = getpass.getuser()
        return x

    pid, status = os.waitpid(pid, 0)
```

Is this the right way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been added as a new feature to the subprocess module in Python 3.9, to the subprocess.Popen constructor:

> New in version 3.9.
>
> If user is not None, the setreuid() system call will be made in the
> child process prior to the execution of the subprocess. If the
> provided value is a string, it will be looked up via pwd.getpwnam()
> and the value in pw_uid will be used. If the value is an integer, it
> will be passed verbatim. (POSIX only)

https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html

Before 3.9, probably best to use that same setreuid() call. Same facilities are there for changing the group too, if you prefer that to user. The code was added in this commit, if you wanna check the specifics of the setting and maybe copy-paste the relevant part to your program: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/2b2ead74382513d0bb9ef34504e283a71e6a706f

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help. unfortunately my code should support python 2.7.11 which is macOS builtin version. I couldn't find any descent way to pass the string generated from child process into parent process. Perhaps you can write me some working example ? Thanks again ! btw, the reason why i'm using fork, is because if I setuid on the same process, I couldn't revert this operation.

Comment: Well maybe your code is fine, perhaps using setreuid() instead of setuid() is just better. If you need to pass data between the processes, subprocesses give you input & output pipes for communication.

Comment: yes, it did the trick. when using setreuid I can reverse the credentials. thanks !